# How can i change isActive from database for disable categories

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i change categories status `isActive` from yes to no, from my magento admin panel it takes too much of time to disable categories, how to disable from database.

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_active` is a category attribute. It's value (Yes/No) is stored in `catalog_category_entity_int` table. 0=No and 1=Yes.

To change `is_active` attribute's value to Yes/No, you have to update `values` column.

For ex, let's say **CatrgoryId is 4**, you can execute following query to update `is_active` attribute.

```
//For setting is_active = Yes
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` SET `value` = '1' WHERE `catalog_category_entity_int`.`entity_id` =4 AND `catalog_category_entity_int`.`attribute_id` = 42;
//For setting is_active = No
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `catalog_category_entity_int`.`entity_id` =4 AND `catalog_category_entity_int`.`attribute_id` = 42;
```

Here **42 is an AttributeId of `is_active`** attribute (that you can find in `eav_attribute` table), so we are using `catalog_category_entity_int`.`attribute_id` = 42 in a query

Comment: There is no changes in my backend

Comment: @JeevaRathinam is any rows updated in database after you executed those queries, also can you please reindex and check once.